# turning SQLite outcome to integer - Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on a project and in need to use new ID's added to my database as numbers,
How do I turn this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + playlistsDBName + " WHERE ID = LAST_INSERT_ROWID";
```

To an integer (or some other number type) that I can use in my Android code?

Comment: Please go check a tutorial/book about SQL

Comment: Sure, there are lots of ways, including the ubiquitous `getInt()`. What have you tried? Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: well I'm doing this:
`public void addNewPlaylist(String DBName, String playlistName) {  
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();  
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
        values.put("PlaylistName", playlistName);  
        db.insert(DBName, null, values);  
        db.close();  
    }`  
and I want to save the ID that I have just added to an integer

Comment: db.insert(DBName, null, values) returns that id as long so you could cast it to an int.

Answer (score 0):

you should change this your method from:

```
public void addNewPlaylist(String DBName, String playlistName) { 
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase(); 
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put("PlaylistName", playlistName); 
db.insert(DBName, null, values); 
db.close();
}
```

to

```
public int addNewPlaylist(String DBName, String playlistName) { 
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase(); 
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put("PlaylistName", playlistName); 
final int id = db.insert(DBName, null, values); 
db.close();
return (int)id;
}
```